# Datatables - horizontal scrolling for only certain columns

Tags: javascript, datatables

The scrollX option in Datatables allows the user to scroll the grid horizontally - however, in my table, I am needing to keep the first two columns in place, but allow the next x columns scroll horizontally. I'm not seeing any good examples of how to do this.

Example:
https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/scroll_x.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could achieve this by changing the relative position of each cell based on the `scrollLeft` value.

```
$('.dataTables_scrollBody').scroll(function (){
    var cols = 2 // how many columns should be fixed
    var container = $(this)
    var offset = container.scrollLeft()
    container.add(container.prev()).find('tr').each(function (index,row){ // .add(container.prev()) to include the header
        $(row).find('td, th').each(function (index,cell){
            if(index>=cols) return
            $(cell).css({position:'relative',left:offset+'px'})
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: Awesome - had to play with the static columns' background-color (the white cells were transparent and "hidden" columns' data was showing through) and set the z-index up on the static column headers for the same reason, but works great.

Comment: For me, to solve overlapping scrolling columns problem, setting background color for static column headers and cells worked. Thanks!